# Write a condition comparing a value to several others tersely

Tags: python, while-loop

I am looking for a better way to write the below code, so that i do not need to use e multiple times.

```
condition = e1>e and e2>e and e3>e and e4>e
```

Comment: Probably something using `all`: `all(e < x for x in (e1, e2, e3, e4))`

Comment: `e < min(e1, e2, e3, e4)`

Comment: @CoryNezin and khelwood those are valid answers, not comments. Why wouldn't you post it as such?

Comment: Just feels too small to warrant a full answer haha

Comment: @khelwood What if `>` is an overloaded operator for `e3`? Just asking.

Comment: The question is why are you asking? If `e` is expensive to calculate or has side-effects, you calculate it once and assign the result to some variable `t` and then do the comparison with `t`. `e < min(e1, e2, e3, e4)` requires all of `e1`, `e2` ,  . . . `e4` to be calculated and compared with one another whereas your original condition could be computed as soon as it is determined, for example, that `e1` is not > `e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly (as long as the comparison operators behave normally on whatever types your values are), a reasonably clear and concise way would be

```
condition = e < min(e1, e2, e3, e4)
```

This involves 4 comparisons (3 to find the minimum of `e1`, `e2`, `e3` and `e4`; and one to compare `e` to the minimum). If you were trying to minimise the number of comparisons (for instance if your values were complex objects and comparing them was a time-consuming operation), you might prefer the slightly more verbose

```
condition = all(e < v for v in (e1, e2, e3, e4))
```

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) short-circuits: it stops iterating as soon as it finds a false value, so this version performs 1 to 4 comparisons depending on the values involved.